# How to use standard SimpsonIntegrator in import org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.integration.SimpsonIntegrator;

Tags: java, integration, apache-commons, numerical-integration, numerical-computing

```
public double evalute(double distance){

    /**
     * equation (3.2)
     */
    this.from = 0;
    this.to = distance;
    this.n = 2;
    return - 10 * Math.log10(Math.exp(-IntSimpson(this.from, this.to, this.n)));
}
```

There is IntSimpson() function i designed manually, but I want to use  standard library! How can i do it and where it can be found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to actually use the integrator object, you need to call the [integrate method](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.5/org/apache/commons/math3/analysis/integration/UnivariateIntegrator.html#integrate(int,%20org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.UnivariateFunction,%20double,%20double)), which takes an instance of [UnivariateFunction](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.5/index.html). If you are on Java 8, this is a single-method interface, so it is automatically a functional interface. Thus, you can pass a lambda or a method reference, as in:

```
final SimpsonIntegrator si = new SimpsonIntegrator();
final double result = si.integrate(50, x -> 2*x, 0, 10);
System.out.println(result + " should be 100");
```

Otherwise, you have to create an implementation of the interface yourself, either by having a class implement it, or by using an anonymous class:

```
final double result = si.integrate(50, new UnivariateFunction() {
        @Override public double value(double x) {
            return 2*x;
        }
    }, 0, 10);
System.out.println(result + " should be 100");
```

Comment: Can i use UnivariateFunction form org.apache.commons.math3?  
If I want to use a sin(x), should I decompose it in a Taylor series?

Answer (score 0):

It works!

```
final SimpsonIntegrator si = new SimpsonIntegrator();
final double result1 = si.integrate(10, x -> 2*Math.pow(x, 1), 0.0, 10.0);
System.out.println(result1 + " should be 100.0");
final double result2 = si.integrate(1000, x -> Math.sin(x), 0.0, Math.PI);
System.out.println(result2 + " should be 2.0000...");
```

Thanks [Javier Martín](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5711725/javier-mart%C3%ADn) !